# Calculate the supremum of $\frac{e^{|\gamma_n+1|}-1}{|\gamma_n+1|}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\{\gamma_n\}$ is a sequence of real number and $\exists M>0$, finite, such that $|\gamma_n|\leq M$, find the supremum of the following sequence:
$$\frac{e^{|\gamma_n+1|}-1}{|\gamma_n+1|}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that this function is monotonically increasing (positive derivative w.r.t. $|\gamma_n+1|$). You know that $\gamma_n\leq M$ or $\gamma_n\geq -M$ so $|\gamma_n+1|\leq M+1$. And therefore $\sup = (e^{M+1}-1)/(M+1)$.